# indexOf() returning -1 when looking for spaces

Tags: java, string, indexof

I'm using indexOf() to look for white spaces while trying to seperate words in a string but the index off keeps returning -1; Here's my code:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the String");
    String s = y.nextLine();
    int words = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     if(s.charAt(i)==' ') words++;
    }
    String[] a = new String[words];
    int l = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= words; i++) {
      int r = s.indexOf(" ");
      a[i] = s.substring(0, r);
      s = s.substring((r + 1), l);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= words; i++) {
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the [mcve] that you have done ? Simply `System.out.println(s.indexOf(" "));` was enough ;). PS : look [`String.split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: @AxelH no since just that one line leaves too much for interpretion, e.g. what `s` looks like and whether and how it is changed before calling `indexOf()`.

Comment: @AlexH Oh, come on, this is minimal enough, and no that one line would not be complete.

Comment: Does `s.indexOf(" ")` _eventually resturn -1 or _always_, i.e. the first time as well? Did you check there actually are spaces in the input, i.e. can you provide some input samples?

Comment: @All, well since nothing is explain, for me this is not enough. That code without input/output ... so you either add the input/output or remove some complexity that could change the behavior..

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't get it; this is the complete code i wrote in order to separate words into individual array elements ;; sample: input-"hello world" gives error on line 14 - "string index out of range"

Comment: Concerning the previous comment of @AlexH: As far as I can see `s` is not changed before the first call of `s.index()`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that due to `for (int i = 0; i <= words; i++)` `indexOf(" ")` will be called at least once even if there is no whitespace in the input - that's because you initialize `words` to 1 and only increment it. Thus you _would_ get -1 for 1-word inputs and an exception out of the following `substring(0, r)`. And as @DM rightly pointed out you will get -1 in the last iteration.

Comment: @Thomas i set words=1 because the no of words in the string is no of space+1

Comment: That's ok but your loop for the spaces results in `words = no_of_spaces` (not +1) because you iterate from `i = 0` to `i <= words`. If you'd use `i < words` instead that would mean you expect words-1 spaces, which should be correct then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you start `words` at 1 and increment it for each space you find.  So if there's one space, `words` is 2.  Then you're trying to look for that many spaces - but there's only 1, so when it runs out of spaces to find, it returns -1 and you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `String.split`, e.g :

```
String s=y.nextLine();
for(String i : s.split(" ")) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```